Cambiar fondo de div
estoy usando una plantilla de una pagina de venta online y no puedo cambiar la imagen de fondo de un div linkeado a bootstrap, lo modifico en la pagina styles.css pero no se aplica el cambio. alguien me ayuda ?

Probaste con control+F5 en el navegador?

muchas gracias !

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
